# Php Regular Expression repeated characters [take max repeat charachers]

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
"ABCCCCCCCCCCCCCDEF"
```

i use the code

```
$value=preg_replace('/[C]{3,}/',"Z",$value);
```

return this

```
"ABZZZZCDEF"
```

How can i get the following result?

```
"ABZCDEF"
```

Comment: It returns *"ABZDEF"* for me. [CodePad](http://codepad.org/RoiH5dOI).

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: Please show the *actual* code you're running, not a simplified example. And perhaps explain what the intention of that code is. I get the result you see when using `/C{3}/` as a search regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$value = preg_replace('/([C]{3})+/', "Z", $value);
```

...or, "Replace one or more groups of three `C`'s with a `Z`."  The code you posted does not work the way you say it does.  I suspect that, as Tim suggested, you're really doing this:

```
$value = preg_replace('/[C]{3}/', "Z", $value);
```

Note the absence of the comma (`,`).  This replaces each group of three `C`'s with a `Z`, where my version replaces *all* groups of three `C`'s with *one* `Z`.

EDIT: ...or, as mario suggested, you're really doing a non-greedy match.  In that case, your "regex" string would be `'/[C]{3,}?/'` or `'/[C]{3,}/U'`.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$a = "ABCCCCCCCCCCCCCDEF";
echo preg_replace('/[C]+/', 'ZC', $a);
?>
```

Gives

```
ABZCDEF
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `preg_replace` seems to default to *ungreedy*. In that case you can change the `{3,}` quantifier with an extra `+` so it means a *minimum* of 3 characters:

```
 = preg_replace('/[C]{3,}+/',
```

Comment: It already means a minimum of three characters. The `+` only makes the quantifier possessive, not changing the result at all in this case.

Comment: Tim's right, making the quantifier possessive doesn't change its greediness, it just disables backtracking.  That means a greedy quantifier will always take the maximum and a non-greedy one will always take the minimum, even if that makes an overall match impossible.

Comment: @AlanMoore: We already noticed that Tim is right. The nomenclature is however not overly relevant to the practical outcome.

Comment: My point is that the nomenclature *is* important, especially since all three phenomena were misnamed from the beginning.  Greedy quantifiers should have been named *eager*, non-greedy ones are better described as *reluctant*, and possessive quantifiers are really *hard-assed*. ;)  Okay, maybe *rigid*--but "possessive" is too easy to interpret as "more greedy", which completely misses the point.